# edit text size and color when highlight

Tags: javascript, jquery

is it possible to change text color, size and font when highlighted im trying to see how i can do this without going through class and id will it be possible

all i need is the script i have the rest this is what i have for my script

```
 $("#fs").change(function() {
//alert($(this).val());
$('.item1').css("font-family", $(this).val());

 });

$("#size").change(function() {
$('.item1').css("font-size", $(this).val() + "px");
});


 $('.foo').click(function(){
$('.item2').css("color", $(this).attr('data-color'));
 });
```

Comment: look at here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3731328/on-text-highlight-event

Comment: im sorry but that is not what im looking for i want to change color font and size when i highlight

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, there is no out of the box solution for such functionality. But you can still use `document.getSelection()` along with key events(such as `mouseup`) to achieve close to what you are looking for.

```
<label>Highlight any text from this sentence</label>
<br>
<label>Highlight any text from this sentence</label>

$(document).on('mouseup',function(e) // delegate a mouseup event on the document
{   
  // locate the target element using e.target
  $(e.target).html($(e.target).html().replace(document.getSelection(), '<span class=\"highlighted\">' + document.getSelection() + '</span>')); // replace the html by replacing the selected text via document.getSelection() with a html enclosed text.
});
```

Example : https://jsfiddle.net/DinoMyte/ez8cgsx7/6/