# HTML Event: how to handle "click" and "text selection" event separately in dojo dgrid-row?

Tags: javascript, html, dojo, dgrid

I am using dojo dgrid for table representation. I have handled a row click event with `grid.on('.dgrid-content .dgrid-row:click', function(){ // Open a Dialog})`. But the problem I am facing here is: while user is trying to select any text on the row with a hope to copy, the event eventually ends up opening the dialog.

As per my knowledge, HTML5 has the support of `ondrag` event, but that is not working in my case. What are the other ways to separate these two events and handle accordingly?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I think its working as expected as you have registered the grid of keyup event. When do you want the dialog to open? onClik of the cell or row

Comment: Might be of some help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3731328/on-text-highlight-event
Other than this you can also track the interval between mousedown and mouseup events to differentiate between click and selection.

Answer (score 2):

You can distinguish select from click in following way inside of your click handler:

```
clickHandler: function () {
            var collapsed = window.getSelection().isCollapsed;
            if (collapsed) {
                console.log("Clicked");
                //Open dialog
            } else {
                console.log("Selected");
                //Do something else
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

You should add set `allowTextSelection` to `true` inside your grid. This allows the user select text inside the rows.

Make sure you read [the documentation](https://github.com/SitePen/dgrid/blob/master/doc/components/mixins/Selection.md) on the topic.

Comment: Thanks for guiding me to an effective way. But for my scenario, this flag is not working.