# javascript - select text in table cell and autofill the input on the same row

Tags: javascript, highlight, onmouseup

Right now I'm using document.onmouseup event to select the text. But I'm only able to specify one input in my code. How do I select the text in the first row and put it in the input in the first row, and do the same thing for the second row?

The code snippet is here (from [On Text Highlight Event?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3731328/on-text-highlight-event)):

```
var t = '';
function gText(e) {
t = (document.all) ? document.selection.createRange().text : document.getSelection();

document.getElementById('input1').value = t;
}

document.onmouseup = gText;
if (!document.all) document.captureEvents(Event.MOUSEUP);
```

https://jsfiddle.net/nrdq71pz/1/

Answer (score 0):

I have used `ShowSelection()` function from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/275761/how-to-get-selected-text-from-textbox-control-with-javascript).

You can add a common class to the `inputs` where you want this feature. Also, you have to attach `mouseup` event to all the inputs. Please see below solution.

```js
var els = document.getElementsByClassName('selection');
function getSelection(textComponent) {
  var selectedText;
  if (textComponent.selectionStart !== undefined) { // Standards Compliant Version
    var startPos = textComponent.selectionStart;
    var endPos = textComponent.selectionEnd;
    selectedText = textComponent.value.substring(startPos, endPos);
  } else if (document.selection !== undefined) { // IE Version
    textComponent.focus();
    var sel = document.selection.createRange();
    selectedText = sel.text;
  }
  return selectedText;
}

for (var i = 0; i < els.length; i++) {
  els[i].addEventListener('mouseup', function() {
    this.value = getSelection(this);
  })
}
```

```html
<table>
  <tr>
    <td>Test code 1</td>
    <td>
      <input type='text' id='input1' class="selection" />
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Test code 2</td>
    <td>
      <input type='text' id='input2' class="selection" />
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: What is expected? input content is replaced by content selected.

Comment: I tried it. The input content is not replace after selection. https://jsfiddle.net/nrdq71pz/3/

Comment: Are you using firefox? Because it is working in chrome and safari

Comment: I've tried chrome and ff. It doesn't seem to work in either browsers.

Comment: If I run your code snippet above in chrome, it gets the following error:
{
  "message": "Script error.",
  "filename": "",
  "lineno": 0,
  "colno": 0
}

Comment: No issues, let me find crossbrowser solution.

Comment: Modified the answer, please test.