# Javascript: Return all text highlighted in Chrome Console

Tags: javascript, google-chrome

I need to get all of the text in a Chrome page that I highlight with my mouse, I know very little about javascript but I found this:

```
var text = "";
if (window.getSelection){
    text = window.getSelection().toString();
    console.log(text)
} else if (document.selection && document.selection.type != 
"Control") {
         text = document.selection.createRange().text;
     }
}
```

Which works once, so is there a good way to iterate this so each time I highlight it prints what I highlighted?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

from https://stackoverflow.com/a/28425297/2553191:

Take a look at the `select` DOM event on [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events/select).

It fires once the mouse or key is released (at least in Chrome 40).

`document.addEventListener('select', callback);`