# How to access the currently highlighted text within a <textarea> in Javascript

Tags: javascript, reactjs

The user will enter text into a HTML textarea on the page. When they highlight part of that text, how can I access the highlighted string? Are there any events triggered by highlighting of text in a textarea element?

This is being done in the context of a react app where the textarea is a component.

Comment: Check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3731328/on-text-highlight-event) out

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5379120/get-the-highlighted-selected-text

Answer (score 2):

Create a function that takes the value of your text area and gets the start and end using `el.selectionStart` and `el.selectionEnd`, then use `el.substring()` to get the selected text within the defined constraints for ***start*** and ***end***.

Lastly, run the function within an eventlistener that is listening to the text areas `select` event.

```js
let textArea = document.getElementById('textArea')
let display = document.getElementById('display')

let getSelectedText = () => {
  let selectedText = textArea.value
  let selStart = textArea.selectionStart
  let selEnd = textArea.selectionEnd
  return selectedText.substring(selStart, selEnd)
}


textArea.addEventListener('select', () => {
  display.innerHTML = `<b>Your selected text is:</b> <i>${getSelectedText()}</i>`
})
```

```html
<textarea id='textArea' rows="7" cols="50">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.</textarea>

<div id="display"></div>
```