# Mouse cursor highighted data

Tags: javascript, php, web

I wanna ask how to get strings data when I highlight the text by mouse. For example when I highlight some text on the website. I should get the text copied to my API automatically. I don't have time to copy-paste. I wanna do it automatically copy and paste when I highlight the text. I have basic knowledge of Js and php.

Answer (score 0):

There isn't any `onhighlightext` event function or anything like that, but a solution would be to bind the onmouseup event to check if any text is selected. See example for selecting highlighted text here: [On Text Highlight Event?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3731328/on-text-highlight-event)

Another part of your question is the copy to clipboard function. Here is a text copy example function, which works for my use cases:

```
  <html>
     <head>
     </head>
     <body>
         <button onclick="toClipboard('Some text!')">Copy me</button>
         <script>
         function toClipboard(str) {
             tc = document.createElement('textarea');
             tc.value = str;
             document.body.appendChild(tc);
             tc.select();
             document.execCommand('copy');
             document.body.removeChild(tc);
         };
         </script>
     </body>
 </html>
```